# Gradle7 Version Catalog: How to use it with buildSrc?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am very excited about the incubating Gradle's [version catalogs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:version-catalog) and have been experimenting with it. I’ve found that the information in my `gradle/libs.versions.toml` is accessible in the `build.gradle.kts` scripts for my app and utility-lib projects.

However, I am unable to use the content of the `toml` file for `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` or [the convention files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html).

The only way that I could build was to hard-code the dependencies into those files, as I did before the version catalog feature.

In the `buildSrc` folder, I created a `settings.gradle.kts` file and inserted the `dependencyResolutionManagement` code for `versionCatalogs`, which is pointing to the same file as for my app and utility-lib projects.

Based on the Gradle7 [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:sharing-catalogs), it seems that sharing a version catalog with `buildSrc` and modules is possible… I’d appreciate a nudge into getting it to work with `buildSrc`, if possible.

Here is a simple sample project, which I created via `gradle init`: [my-version-catalog](https://gitlab.com/abitofhelp.shared/my-version-catalog.git)

Thank you for your time and help,

Mike

Comment: I found the following link, which is fairly current and it provides more details about this use-case.  https://melix.github.io/blog/#_can_i_use_a_version_catalog_to_declare_plugin_versions

Comment: For reference the good link is [Version Catalog FAQ by Cédric Champeau](https://melix.github.io/blog/2021/03/version-catalogs-faq.html#_can_i_use_a_version_catalog_to_declare_plugin_versions)

Answer (score 46):

With Gradle 7.3.3, it is possible. Note [version catalogs are GA since Gradle 7.4](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/release-notes.html#promoted-features)

> The code snippet assumes Gradle is at least 7.4, but if you need them prior that version, insert `enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")` at the beginning of each `settings.gradle.kts`.

#### Using `buildSrc`

`buildSrc/settings.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from(files("../gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}
```

`buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.gradleplugin.intellij) // <- the lib reference
}
```

You can even use the version catalog for plugins

`gradle/libs.versions.toml`

```ini
...

[plugins]
kotlin-jvm = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm", version.ref = "kotlin" }
jetbrains-changelog = { id = "org.jetbrains.changelog", version.ref = "changelog-plugin" }
jetbrains-intellij = { id = "org.jetbrains.intellij", version.ref = "intellij-plugin" }
hierynomus-license = { id = "com.github.hierynomus.license", version.ref = "license-plugin" }
nebula-integtest = { id = "nebula.integtest", version.ref = "nebula-integtest-plugin" }
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("java")
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.jvm)
    alias(libs.plugins.nebula.integtest)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.intellij)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.changelog)
    alias(libs.plugins.hierynomus.license)
}
```

Note for accessing the catalog within scripts, please refer to the below section, the trick is the same.

#### Using *convention plugins* and *included build*

In the main project include a the Gradle project that holds the convention plugins.

`build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
includeBuild("convention-plugins") // here it's a subfolder
```

`convention-plugins/settings.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from(files("../gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "convention-plugins"
```

> The trick to enable convention plugins to access the version catalog is split in two part, add an *ugly* implementation dependency that locate where the version catalog generated classes are located.
>
> ```kotlin
> libs.javaClass.superclass.protectionDomain.codeSource.location
> ```
>
> Then in the convention plugin refer to the *libs extension* via `Project::the`.
>
> ```kotlin
> val libs = the<LibrariesForLibs>()
> ```
>
> This is tracked by [gradle/gradle#15383](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15383).

`convention-plugins/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.gradleplugin.kotlin.jvm)

    // https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15383
    implementation(files(libs.javaClass.superclass.protectionDomain.codeSource.location))
}
```

And in the actual convention plugin

```kotlin
import org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
}

// https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15383
val libs = the<LibrariesForLibs>()

dependencies {
    detektPlugins(libs.bundles.kotlinStuff) // access catalog entries
}
```

The `org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs` class is generated by gradle is somewhere in local gradle folder `./gradle/<version>/dependency-accessors/<hash>/classes`

---

Quick note that older IntelliJ IDEA currently (2022.3) reports `alias(libs.gradleplugin.thePlugin)` as an error in the editor,
**although the dependencies are correctly resolved**.
This tracked by [KTIJ-19369](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19369/False-positive-cant-be-called-in-this-context-by-implicit-receiver-with-plugins-in-Gradle-version-catalogs-as-a-TOML-file), the ticket indicates this is actually a bug in Gradle Kotlin DSL [gradle/gradle#22797](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/22797), and someone made a simple [IntelliJ IDEA plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18949-gradle-libs-error-suppressor) to hide this error until resolved.

Comment: For the libs.versions.toml file in the gradle directory, you don't need to add VersionCatalog section.  It the file is present in that directory the libs version catalog is available.  With gradle 7.4, the enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS") is no longer needed.

Comment: @TomRutchik I don't think this works for buildSrc, or any subprojects (as included build) as it's considered as a different project which means the location has to be set explicitly.

Comment: Brice, you're right about buildSrc and included build.  You should however have access to the version catalog in the buildSrc/build.gradle.kts without adding the dependency but the buildSrc code won't! I'm somewhat curious if adding that dependency to an external built custom plugin would allow the custom plugin to have access to the libs catalog in the project that it gets applied.  I'm going to give that a try, but somehow I don't think that'll work!

Comment: Hi, let me know what you did find out!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question fully. It makes the catalog accessible to the `buildSrc/build.gradle` , but not to the convention plugins. Do you have an example of using the catalog extension to reference the contents of `libs.versions.toml`?

Comment: I also am stuck on this, the above makes it accessible from `build.gradle.kts` but not in `src/main/kotlin/my-kotlin-library-conventions.kts` for example =(

Comment: @GavinRay @Pytry I do have convention plugins as well, but I migrated to _included build_ rather than `buildSrc`. I'll complement the answer right away with what I have.

Comment: @Brice I owe you a beer mate, I can't believe you figured out those billion layers of hacks. Holy hell that's one nightmare to get working right... they need to revisit Version Catalog support for buildSrc I think

Comment: Thank you @GavinRay, but really this is also luck and sharing knowledge. Actually the trick is fairly simple, and I believe part of it makes sense. But clearly the usability in the context of convention plugins (either in buildSrc or _included build_) is kinda bad.

Comment: If you ever want to use this in a convention plugin written in kotlin you can also duplicate the existing `libs` extension function on `Project` e.g. `val Project.libs: LibrariesForLibs get() = (this as ExtensionAware).extensions.getByName("libs") as LibrariesForLibs`

Answer (score 1):

Brice, it looks like a can of worms to go down that path, particularly for my situation, where I'm trying to use a libs.version.toml file from an android project, but the custom plugin is of course from a java/kotlin project. I tried creating the libs file by hardwiring the path to the toml file in the custom plugin. It might work if both were java projects, but I never tried that since that's not what I'm after. The ideal solution would be for the plugin to use the libs file from the project it is applied to, but it looks like the version catalog needs to be created in the settings file, before you even have access to "Project", so that's why you would have to hardwire the path.

Short answer. No, but there are other techniques for a custom plugin to get project version data from the project it is applied to.

Comment: What you can do so that the custom plugin gets access to a shared version catalog is to use gradle "version-catalog" plugin.  You can use that to publish a version catalog to a repository.  You can then import that publish version catalog in your custom plugin. The only caveat is that the project and the custom plugin both need to agree on the shared published version catalog.  For many situations, that's all you need.  If you have two project that use different shared version catalogs, you can't use the same custom plugin.  You can however, override values in an imported version catalog.

Comment: For clarity, I talking about external custom plugins, not buildSrc plugin