# Unresolved reference: Libraries - buildSrc

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, dependency-management, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to switch to using Kotlin DSL to get dependencies versions from an object Kotlin file instead of gradle files. When I do a gradle sync it is unable to resolve reference, but I'm able to click on file (Libraries) from build.gradle.kts . I haven't made any other changes to build.gradle or settings.gradle . The issue isn't specific to Jackson and I tried this in multiple projects and read documentation and searched for answers before posting the question.

I get a build.gradle.kts:15:20: Unresolved reference: Libraries

This is the structure of my project

```
build.gradle
settings.gradle
+buildSrc
    build.gradle.kts
    +src
        +main
            +kotlin
                Libraries.kt
```

This is the my build.gradle.kts file

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
    java
    `java-gradle-plugin`
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(Libraries.Jackson.core)
//    implementation(Libraries.anotherJackson)
}
```

This is the kotlin Libraries.kt file

```
object Libraries {
    val Jackson = JacksonLibraries
    const val anotherJackson = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1"

}

object JacksonLibraries {
    const val core = "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${Versions.Jackson.core}"
}

object Versions {
    object Jackson {
        const val core = "2.11.1"
        const val annotations = "2.11.1"
        const val databind = "2.11.1"
    }
}
```

If I try it without the Libraries file it works fine.

```
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1")
```

But neither of these two work

```
implementation(Libraries.Jackson.core)
implementation(Libraries.anotherJackson)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you add `import Libraries` to the top of your root `build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now. Are you trying to access `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Libraries.kt` in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`? Because that's not possible, and isn't necessary.

Comment: @aSemy Would you please elaborate on why it is not possible? Also, I need Libraries to access dependencies names and version implementation. Do you have an alternative suggestion?

Here are some sample tutorials online where it was implemented.

https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/kotlin-dsl-gradle-scripts-in-android-made-easy-b8e2991e2ba

https://betterprogramming.pub/gradle-dependency-management-with-buildsrc-and-kotlin-dsl-1de958eab166

https://proandroiddev.com/better-dependencies-management-using-buildsrc-kotlin-dsl-eda31cdb81bf

Comment: Basically it's not possible to use `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Libraries.kt` in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` for the same reason you can't use `<root>/src/main/kotlin/Libraries.kt` in `<root>/build.gradle.kts`. The Gradle build scripts are used to build a project, so they can't use the output of the same project. However `buildSrc` [is treated as included build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources), so the contents of `buildSrc/src/main/...` will be available in `<root>/build.gradle.kts`.

Comment: It's possible to share versions between `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` and `<root>/build.gradle.kts` with [Version Catalogs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67795324/4161471) or logic with [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#composite_build_intro), but I'm not clear on which you want. Could you explain a bit more about what you want to achieve? Are you planning on writing a Gradle task or plugin that needs the Jackson library? Do you just want to align versions, or do you also want to share logic?

Comment: Thanks @aSemy for your explanation. I assigned a bounty to this question and I'm trying to give it to you, I think I might have to wait 7 days. I did manage to link to Libraries file when implementing from root/app/build.gradle

Ultimately I have the following situation. We have multiple microservices application, each with its own build.gradle. I will have these libraries added to an SDK and  where each build will link to the Libraries file which I will put in the SDK (an implemented library) and get the dependency versions. The SDK only contains java/kotlin files. Not sure of a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you trying to access `./buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Libraries.kt` in `./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`? Because that's not possible, and isn't necessary.

Basically it's not possible to use `./buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Libraries.kt` in `./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` for the same reason you can't use `<root>/src/main/kotlin/Libraries.kt` in `./<root>/build.gradle.kts`. The Gradle build scripts can't use the output of the projects they're trying to build.

However `buildSrc` [is treated as included build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources), so the contents of `./buildSrc/src/main/...` will be available in `<root>/build.gradle.kts`

### Version alignment

#### Version Catalogs

It's possible to share versions between `./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` and `<root>/build.gradle.kts` with Version Catalogs.

The [`libs.versions.toml` file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:conventional-dependencies-toml) is the easiest way to do this.

In short,

1. Use Gradle 7.4+
2. Create a `<root>/gradle/libs.versions.toml` file
3. Define your dependencies, e.g.

   ```
   [versions]
   groovy = "3.0.5"

   [libraries]
   groovy-core = { module = "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy", version.ref = "groovy" }
   ```
4. In `<root>/build.gradle.kts`, or any `<root>/settings.gradle.kts` `include(...)`-ed subproject, you can now access the dependencies (you might need to refresh IntelliJ a few times for the auto-complete to load).

   ```kotlin
   dependencies {
     implementation(libs.groovy.core)
   }
   ```

You can use the same Version Catalog in any project by [loading the file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:sharing-catalogs). If you wanted to host it and download it, that would work too!

#### Version Platform

If you want to align versions across several separated projects, you can follow the documentation here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html

Version Platforms are a little more structured than Version Catalogs. They're kind of like Gradle's versions of Maven BOMs, except they're more flexible of course!

In short,

1. Create a Gradle project, and apply the [Java Platform Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html) and [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)
2. Define your constraints
3. Publish it to a Maven repo
4. Apply it to any project as a platform dependency

   ```kotlin
   dependencies {
     implementation(platform("my.company:our-own-version-platform:1.2.3"))

     // no need for a version, if our-own-version-platform provides it!
     implementation("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy") 
   }
   ```

Comment: so after going the `libs.versions.toml` path I'm able to reference the versions/dependencies in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` but not in `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/...` files – I added the definition to `buildSrc/settings.gradle.kts`, is there another place I need to put it?

Comment: That's not officially supported yet ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15383)). Either set up a Version Platform (which can use the `libs.versions.toml`), or try [a workaround](https://melix.github.io/blog/2021/03/version-catalogs-faq.html#_but_how_can_i_use_the_catalog_in_plugins_defined_in_buildsrc)

Answer (score 1):

At least in Gradle 8.3 i got it to work with:

```kotlin
// file: buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/javaconventions.gradle.kts
val versionCatalog = rootProject.extensions.getByType<VersionCatalogsExtension>().named("libs")
java {
    val javaVersion = versionCatalog.findVersion("java").get().requiredVersion.toInt()
}
```