# How can I refer to libraries defined in a shared Gradle build plugin from another build script?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to define libraries in a common location. So in an `our.libraries.gradle.kts` script in a shared build plugin, I have this:

```kotlin
inner class Libraries {
    val junit get() = ...
    val junitParams get() = ...
}

val libraries = Libraries()
project.extra["libraries"] = libraries
```

In one of the *Groovy* build scripts elsewhere in the project, this is referred to like this:

```
allprojects {
    dependencies {
        testImplementation libraries.junit
    }
}
```

This works fine.

So I try converting that script to Kotlin:

```kotlin
allprojects {
    dependencies {
        "testImplementation"(libraries.junit)
    }
}
```

And now this fails, because it can't see the `libraries` property on the project, so I try explicitly pulling it out at the start:

```kotlin
val libraries: Libraries by project.extra
allprojects {
    dependencies {
        "testImplementation"(libraries.junit)
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work either, because the script can't find the `Libraries` class.

I also tried putting `Libraries` in `Libraries.kt`, but then I can't seem to call methods like `exclude` using named parameters because for whatever reason Gradle doesn't support using the DSL when it's moved to a top-level class.

This is sort of similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753733/ext-in-buildscript-can-not-be-recognised-by-gradle-kotlin-dsl), but in the case of wanting to put in simple types, everything works fine. Which is to say, I *can* put the libraries in as a `Map`, but then any time I want to reference one, I have to write this:

```kotlin
        "testImplementation"(libraries["junit"]!!)
```

This is obviously ugly, so I have been trying to avoid it.

So I'm stumped again.

This is part of a long saga trying to get this to work in many different ways, so the essential question is still the same: how can we define all our libraries in one location, and then refer to those in a type-safe way from other build scripts?

Recently, Gradle added shared dependencies via a TOML file, but that method only supports the version numbers, whereas our library definitions also include the excluded dependencies.

It was hard to put a completely self-contained example in the question because multiple files are involved, so [here's a test repo](https://github.com/hakanai/gradle-dsl-cross-script-reference-problem).

Comment: From looking at your example repo you're using `apply(...)` to directly reference the plugin. This only configures the Gradle build, and doesn't share your `Libraries` class. Instead either define a 'proper' plugin and use [`includeBuild(...)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html), or publish it to a Maven repo and access it via the plugin ID.

Comment: I think using the [`version-catalog` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:version-catalog-plugin) will achieve what you want. You essentially define your own BOM, and you can also set exclusions or more complex logic. [See this answer for an intro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71562588/4161471).

Comment: @aSemy as far as I could tell when I evaluated it (and this is also mentioned in the question already), the version catalogs literally only let you declare the versions, not the exclusions and other things.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. I meant to link the [`java-platform` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_version_alignment.html#aligning_versions_natively_with_gradle).