# Convention plugin error org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForDeps not present

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to build convention plugins for a common configuration, e.g. ktlint. They are stored under build-configuration/plugin/convention.

```
class KtlintConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

   override fun apply(target: Project) {
      return with(target) {
         pluginManager.apply(deps.plugins.ktlint.get().pluginId)

         extensions.configure<KtlintExtension> {
            // ...
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**build-configuration/plugin/convention/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
   `kotlin-dsl`
}

group = "com.example"

dependencies {
   compileOnly(deps.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin)
   compileOnly(deps.ktor.gradle.plugin)
   compileOnly(deps.ktlint.gradle.plugin)

   compileOnly(files(deps.javaClass.superclass.protectionDomain.codeSource.location))
}

gradlePlugin {
   plugins {
      register("ktlint-plugin") {
         id = "ktlint-plugin"
         implementationClass = "KtlintConventionPlugin"
      }
   }
}
```

I also have an extension function to get dependencies defined in TOML file (stored in `gradle/deps.versions.toml`) in **build-configuration/plugin/convention/src/main/kotlin/com/example/VersionCatalog.kt**

```
import org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForDeps
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.the

internal val Project.deps: LibrariesForDeps
   get() = the()
```

**build-configuration/settings.gradle.kts**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
   repositories {
      gradlePluginPortal()
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
   }
   versionCatalogs {
      create("deps") {
         from(files("../gradle/deps.versions.toml"))
      }
   }
}
rootProject.name = "build-configuration"
include(":plugin:convention")
```

When I include `ktlint` plugin in root `build.gradle.kts`, Gradle synchronization always fails.

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'ktlint-plugin']
> Failed to apply plugin 'ktlint-plugin'.
   > Type org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForDeps not present
```

I can see the class generated in .gradle/.../LibrariesForDeps, but under the project's root, not the plugin's one.

The whole build-configuration module is included in root settings.gradle.kts:

```
includeBuild("build-configuration")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new project and followed [this approach](https://github.com/PoisonedYouth/gradle-convention-plugin). There is only one difference. I had to have the block below in both `settings.gradle.kts` files, root, and build-configuration:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
   versionCatalogs {
      create("deps") {
         from(files("../gradle/deps.versions.toml"))
      }
   }
}
```

It just doesn't work for me without this duplication.

Also, I'm not using any module within the build-configuration plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `libs` doesn't work in convention plugins, but there are some workarounds in the issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15383

But I don't think you need it. Instead the version can be defined in a single place: the included build's `build.gradle.kts`, which has access to the version catalog DSL.

1. define the *Maven* coordinates of the ktlint plugin in `libs.versions.toml`

   ```ini
   [libraries]

   gradlePlugin-ktlint = { module = "org.jlleitschuh.gradle:ktlint-gradle", version = "11.1.0" }
   ```

   I prefer prefixing such dependencies with `gradlePlugin` to distinguish them from 'regular' project dependencies.

   (The Maven coordinates are listed in [the Gradle Plugin Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint), under the 'legacy' application as a `classpath` dependency)
2. Add a dependency on ktlint in the included build, `build-configuration/build.gradle.kts`

   ```kotlin
   plugins {
     `kotlin-dsl`
   }

   dependencies {
     implementation(libs.deps.gradlePlugin.ktlint)
   }
   ```
3. Now the ktlint plugin will be available on the classpath, and you can apply it as normal in a convention plugin, no version necessary.

   In a precompiled script plugin:

   ```kotlin
   // ./build-configuration/src/main/kotlin/my-ktlint-convention.gradle.kts

   plugins {
     id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") // version is provided by build.gradle.kts
   }
   ```

   Or in a traditional class plugin (which will require registering via [`gradlePlugins {}`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project)):

   ```
   // ./build-configuration/src/main/kotlin/KtlintConventionPlugin.kt
   class KtlintConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
     override fun apply(target: Project) {
       target.apply(plugin = "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint")
       target.extensions.configure<KtlintExtension> {
            // ...
       }
     }
   }
   ```

#### See also

For more information about buildSrc convention plugins, these answers are related:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71562588/4161471
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/71892685/4161471

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've followed [this repo](https://github.com/MaximillianLeonov/Cinemax/tree/main/build-logic) and [this one](https://github.com/PoisonedYouth/gradle-convention-plugin). The former looks basically what I wanted to achieve. However, I cannot sync my project, I'm most likely missing something.