# How to import class defined in a init script to build.gradle?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm writing a gradle extension in an init-script but I don't know how to reference the extension in build.gralde.

```
// init.gradle.kts


allprojects {
  extensions.create("message", MessageExtension::class)
}

open class MessageExtension(objects: ObjectFactory) {
    // A configurable greeting
    val greeting: Property<String> = objects.property()
}
```

I can reference `message` in groovy build.gradle, it's happy to pull `message` from thin air.

```
// build.gradle (groovy)
message.greeting = "hi"
```

But build.gradle.kts references to `messages` are unresolved.

```
// build.gradle.kts
   message.greeting = "hi"
// ^ Unresolved reference: message
```

If I try to find the extension by type the class is also unresolved.

```
// build.gradle.kts
val messages = project.extensions.findByType(MessageExtension::class)
//                                           ^ Unresolved reference: MessageExtension
```

I've tried declaring a `package` in my init.gradle.kts and importing it, but the import is also unresolved.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible. Maybe this might be somehow relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/55335866/12042788

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
the<MessageExtension>().greeting = "hi"
```

Comment: MessageExtension is unresolved, it's the equivalent to findByType.